# Performing a mysql query from node/express server using ? placeholder getting syntax error | npm mysql package

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, reactjs, express

I can't seem to get my head around this. I have a connection set up correctly and am able to, from the frontend, get data from my database but am having trouble with some syntax I believe. I have user input being stored in "searchTerm" that I am trying to run a query against using a placeholder ?.

The code I am having trouble with is

```
app.get('/api/get', (req, res)=> {
    const searchTerm = req.body.searchTerm;
    const sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE MATCH(questionTitle) AGAINST(?)";
    db.query(sqlSelect, searchTerm, (err, result) => {
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

The issue isn't with the query because it turns out a positive result in workbench and also works properly when I hardcode the user inputted value. I'm getting an Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?)'

I'm stumped because this is what I have for a post and it works as expected:

```
app.post('/answer/insert', (req, res, next)=> {
    const question = req.body.question;
    const answer = req.body.answer;
    const category = req.body.category;
    const today = req.body.today;

    const sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO questions (questionTitle, questionBody, category, questionDate) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    db.query(sqlInsert, [question, answer, category, today], (err, result) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE: Frontend looks like this**

```
function startSearch(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(searchTerm);
        Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/get', {
            searchTerm: searchTerm,
        })
       .then(function(response) {
          console.log("It worked, response is: ", response)
         
       }).catch(function() {
          console.log("error");
       });
        };
```

My post request works and it looks like this:

```
const submitReview = () => {
        Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/answer/insert', {
            question: question, answer: answer, category: category, today: today,
        }).then(()=> {
            console.log(category + question + answer + today);
            alert('successful insert');
        })
        .catch(()=> {
            console.log(category + question + answer + today);

            alert('it didnt work');
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Original Answer

As described here https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#performing-queries, the query parameters need to be passed in as an array.

Change

```
db.query(sqlSelect, searchTerm, (err, result) => {
    res.send(result);
});
```

to

```
db.query(sqlSelect, [searchTerm], (err, result) => {
    res.send(result);
});
```

## Update

Your frontend called `startSearch` uses a GET request. This will not send anything in the body. I would use a query string (changed from parameter, a query parameter is something after a ? at the end of a URL). Assuming you are using Express.JS, take a look here https://stackabuse.com/get-query-strings-and-parameters-in-express-js/. It should point you in the right direction.

If you need specific code, this will do what you want. The above link will help you understand how this works.

Change the backend from

```
app.get('/api/get', (req, res)=> {
    const searchTerm = req.body.searchTerm;
    const sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE MATCH(questionTitle) AGAINST(?)";
    db.query(sqlSelect, searchTerm, (err, result) => {
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

to

```
app.get('/api/get/:searchTerm', (req, res)=> {
    const searchTerm = req.params.searchTerm;
    const sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE MATCH(questionTitle) AGAINST(?)";
    db.query(sqlSelect, [searchTerm], (err, result) => {
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

and the frontend from

```
function startSearch(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(searchTerm);
        Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/get', {
            searchTerm: searchTerm,
        })
       .then(function(response) {
          console.log("It worked, response is: ", response)
         
       }).catch(function() {
          console.log("error");
       });
};
```

to

```
function startSearch(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(searchTerm);
        Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/get/' + searchTerm)
       .then(function(response) {
          console.log("It worked, response is: ", response)
         
       }).catch(function() {
          console.log("error");
       });
};
```

Comment: I wish that was it :/ , I had tried that and am getting an array of 0 Thanks for your answer

Comment: Add a `console.log(req.body)` above `const searchTerm = req.body.searchTerm` and ensure that there is a `searchTerm` value in the request body. It seems as if `searchTerm` isn't being passed in `req.body`.

Comment: You're right well that's helpful! The code on my frontend is

`function startSearch(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(searchTerm);
        Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/get', {
            searchTerm: searchTerm,
        })
       .then(function(response) {
          console.log("It worked, response is: ", response)
         
       }).catch(function() {
          console.log("error");
       });
        };`

Comment: Not very user friendly format sorry, but the searchTerm does have the proper value but It's not being passed to my server. My post req follows the same format though so not sure what the issue would be?

`const submitReview = () => {
        Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/answer/insert', {
            question: question, answer: answer, category: category, today: today,
        }).then(()=> {
            console.log(category + question + answer + today);
            alert('successful insert');`

Comment: Updated my initial question to include the frontend code!

Comment: Code is working now That was incredibly helpful thanks for the insight and direction really appreciate it! I don't have enough reputation to cast a vote unfortunately but wish you well

Comment: Thank you. I was very happy to help. Good luck on your coding journey. :)